# Prograurd Duplicate zip entry

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with signing and releasing an APK. I get Duplicate zip entry warnings and one error, Here is the code:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [gcm.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.2.4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [httpmime-4.2.2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [splunk-mint-4.2.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [support-annotations-24.0.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Android\Android_Project\myapp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Amir Mahmoud\.android\build-cache\3936c6cf75e73634f829890fcc2030092ab8dabe\output\jars\classes.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.class]))
```

I even tried adding packaging options to the gradle but it did not work this is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 70
        versionName "7.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:25'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    //    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"
    //    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.3'
    //    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.2.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.1.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
//    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}
```

I am stuck on this project for a few days and I don't know what to do with it, any helps are welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Jared’s answer, if you receive an error about a duplicate `.class` file(s), not just the `META-INF/` files, you may need to exclude the offending module that includes the duplicate `.class` file(s).

You will need to identify which dependency is including the module with the duplicate `.class` entries and exclude that module from said dependency.

You can use the Gradle command: `./gradlew app:dependencies` to list the complete dependency graph. Where “`app:`” is the name of your project's module/app.

After using the `./gradlew app:dependencies` command you should look through the list of dependencies and find the one that is including the offending module with the duplicate `.class` entries.

As an example, lets say that `com.android.support:support-v4` is the module with the duplicate classes that are causing these errors. Here's how to exclude that duplicate module from your dependency:

```
//Your dependency that includes the module with the duplicates.
compile('com.my.project:my-module:0.1') {
        //exclude the offending module so there won’t be duplicates.
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        //maybe you need to exclude a group also?...
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Ionic, and I don't have the compile() lines. Anyway reinstalling android platform did the trick.