# Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to solve one problem for a few days.
When I run my app, I get this error:

```
Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry 
[simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:org/simpleframework/xml/Attribute.class]
```

And In more detail (here It says : **simple-xml-2.7.1.jar** but I have simple-xml-2.3.4.jar like in the image)

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Alfonso\Documents\AndroidStudioProjectsNew\Business\VOIPMonitoring\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] 
(Can't read [C:\Users\Alfonso\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.simpleframework\simple-
xml\2.7.1\dd91fb744c2ff921407475cb29a1e3fee397d411\simple-xml-2.7.1.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:org/simpleframework/xml/Attribute.class]))


Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [simple-xml-2.7.1.jar:org/simpleframework/xml/Attribute.class]
at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
```

Associated Proguard files are empty.

After the comand: gradlew clean I get: 
[image]

Here where is the library (I am using external library )

[image]

My Progect build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
 }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
        maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url  "https://dl.bintray.com/httprequester/maven" }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'}
    }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

My Module: android-ngn-stack build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}


allprojects {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url  "https://dl.bintray.com/httprequester/maven" }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'}
        }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module:app build.gradle where i think there is the problem

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "monitoring.voip.business.tim.voipmonitoring"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 24
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.3"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
        compile project(':android-ngn-stack')
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
             exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile project(path: ':librarynetwork')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.4.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.10.0'
        compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
        compile 'com.loopeer.library:cardstack:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
        // Room
        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
        compile 'ir.bpadashi.requester:requester:1.1.6'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


}

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                        details.useVersion '25.0.0'
                    }
            }
        }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I know it's stupid answer but have you tried `./gradlew clean` first.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 i deleted the .gradle folder. Is It the same right?

Comment: I don't think so. Try doing both it can't hurt.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 I get this error:   Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location. I add the immage of my error in my question

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you since I don't know what to do. Try reinstalling google api images via sdk manager, updating to newest Android Studio(stable branch), use new gradle functions(implementation instead of compile and similar described in the new image you posted) and stuff like that since it seems as the problem is not in your code.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 in the error says : simple-xml-2.7.1.jar  but i dont't use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your problem. You put `simple-xml-2.3.4.jar` in your dependencies and some of your other dependencies have dependency on `simple-xml-2.7.1.jar`.

Use `./gradlew <module-name>:dependencies | grep simple-xml` to find out if this is the case and search for dependency that uses it.

It would be best for you to try compiling without `simple-xml-2.3.4.jar` and see if code runs with `simple-xml-2.7.1.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

> simple-xml-2.7.1.jar but i dont't use it..

**You** may not, but one of those *other libraries does*

Simple XML JAR is not a JNI library, so I don't know why you'd put it in `jniLibs`, but...

Delete your JAR, use this dependency instead

```
 compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

After days, I solved my problem starting with a new project and adding incrementally dependencies

The problem was caused from dependencies into my gradle file in conflict with my external library.

I discovered this thanks the command

```
    ./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

where app is your project module.

The conflict problem are localized where you see the arrow (-->) .

You can exclude that dependency using "exclude module" like below
(but I have prefered starting from new empty project and I will exclude dependencies problems after )

As an example, lets say that com.android.support:support-v4 is the module with the duplicate classes that are causing these errors. Here's how to exclude that duplicate module from your dependency:

```
//Your dependency that includes the module with the duplicates.
 compile('com.my.project:my-module:0.1') {
    //exclude the offending module so there won’t be duplicates.
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    //maybe you need to exclude a group also?...
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

references to same solution

[Prograurd Duplicate zip entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496103/prograurd-duplicate-zip-entry)

[Prograurd Duplicate zip entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496103/prograurd-duplicate-zip-entry)