# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get the error Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$1 whenever I try to run my app on the emulator

Heres my app build.gradle file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh1td.png)

and project build.gradle file. Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVLIx.png)

Comment: You have conflicting dependencies. See my solution to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453129/2371425

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837344/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-app-backstackrecord